# Mysql random record using join

Tags: mysql, sql, random, inner-join

How do select random record from a specific table when using join query?
I have below two table and I will like to select random `pid`

Users

```
id   | name.  | uid
-----|--------|-----
1    | Peter  | p1
2    | Hana   | p3
3    | John   | p4
4    | Joe    | p2
```

Packages

```
pid  | tag      | puid
-----|----------|------
1    | PHP      | p1   
2    | JAVA     | p1
3    | CSS      | p2
4    | SQL      | p1
5    | PYTHON   | p3
6    | HTML     | p1
7    | SWIFT    | p1
```

Query

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
FROM users u

INNER JOIN packages p
ON u.uid = p.puid

WHERE u.uid = "p1"
ORDER BY RAND()

LIMIT 2
```

Comment: How is the query you show not doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `RAND()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` to join one random related row. For example:

```
with p as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by puid order by rand()) as rn 
  from packages
)
select *
from users u
left join p on p.puid = u.uid and p.rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 id  name   uid  pid   tag     puid  rn   
 --- ------ ---- ----- ------- ----- ---- 
 1   Peter  p1   4     SQL     p1    1    
 2   Hana   p3   5     PYTHON  p3    1    
 3   John   p4   null  null    null  null 
 4   Joe    p2   3     CSS     p2    1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rpbD2pJntbgfnmf2Sdb1Xq/0).